# SWIFT: Update Screen (SKView) now

Tags: swift, view, screen, skview

My app needs a lot of time for initialization. So I created a screen for the user, then I want to show it to him and then I can continue in calculation. But I don't know how to simply start screenupdating. If the process ended it is done automatically. (but too late!) :-)

Comment: can you show us what you have done? some code or some more explanations?

Comment: It is a game. It needs a initialization before it can be started. But screen can be shown before last part on initialization is done. This should happen.
I need a call to get screen shown like I would end initialization at this point.

Comment: if i was writing the code and if there was like 2 views i would do like this...first let initiate the App! as i think you have handle that! you can do it in a class! and use something like do-while,while,etc. and you can use performSegueWithIdentifier function to get to that view! if it is possible paste some code so then we can find out how you initiate the app and how the views are!

Comment: I used viewDidLoad for initializing. But now it's clear to me. As long as this function is not complete nothing will happen. So I think I have to create a timer, which will call the second initialization part after a second, so viewDidLoad can terminate successfuly.